# VBA for copying multiple web pages and pasteing into separate excel sheets

Tags: excel, macros, vba

I have a file with formula created links in an excel file.  I have created buttons and macros to

1. convert the formulas to links
2. open all the links in Internet Explorer
3. Copy a single web page from a single link and paste into excel on a separate sheet

What I'm needing is a way to loop the 3rd macro to copy the contents of the web page from every link not just the first one and paste each web page contents from each link into it's own sheet within the same workbook.

```
Sub OpenHyperLinks()
'Update 20141124
Dim xHyperlink As Hyperlink
Dim WorkRng As Range
On Error Resume Next
xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address,  Type:=8)
For Each xHyperlink In WorkRng.Hyperlinks
    xHyperlink.Follow
Next


End Sub
Sub HyperAdd()

'Converts each text hyperlink selected into a working hyperlink

For Each xCell In Selection
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=xCell, Address:=xCell.Formula
Next xCell

End Sub
Sub pasteMyWebP()
Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
Dim IE As Object

Const strURL As String = "https://www.aiproducts.com/dealer              /OrderDetl.htm?OrderNumber=10110630&InvoiceNumber=8042869"


Set wb = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate strURL

Do While IE.ReadyState <> 4
DoEvents
Loop

IE.ExecWB 17, 2
IE.ExecWB 12, 2

ActiveSheet.Paste Range("a1")
IE.Visible = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code. It's a bit general, based on your code, but the concept is there. You may need to modify a few things. Also, you will not need to convert the formulas to hyperlinks.

```
Sub ScrapeWebPagetoNewSheet()

Dim wsLinks As Worksheet
Set wsLinks = Worksheets("Links") 'change name to the correct worksheet
Dim rngLinks As Range, rngLink As Range
Set rngLinks = ws.Range("A1:A10") 'change range to correct range

Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 'creating it here so it remains open

For Each rngLink In rngLinks
    pasteMyWebP rngLink.Formula, ThisWorkbook, IE
Next rngLink

IE.Quit

End Sub

Sub pasteMyWebP(sURL As String, wb As Workbook, IE As Object)

    Dim wsPaste As Worksheet
    Set wsPaste = wb.Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))

    With IE

        .Visible = True
        .Navigate strURL

        Do While .ReadyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop

        .ExecWB 17, 2
        .ExecWB 12, 2

        wsPaste.Paste Range("a1")

        .Visible = False

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm used that and modified the fields for name and range but the debug error is stating "Compile error" Argument not optional for        pasteMyWebP rngLink line

Comment: @Neener - sorry, forgot through the `IE` object into the sub call when I edited it. I have fixed this.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the help!